# Pandas - positive volume index without for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute the positive volume index on a stock time series (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pvi.asp), and I'd like to do it oneshot (without for loop).

The input is a classic stock dataframe with OHLC and Volume as columns and datetime as index.

This is what I was thinking:

```
df['PVI'] = 0
df['Volume'].diff() > 0
prev_c = df['Close'].shift() 
prev_pvi = df['PVI'].shift()
df['PVI'] = np.where(df['Volume'].diff() > 0,
                         prev_pvi + (df['Close'] - prev_c / prev_c * df['PVI'].shift()),
                         df['PVI'].shift())
```

But I get a `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns`.
I can easily split it in a for loop with an if condition on volume but I wanted to write more pandonic coeds.

In order to have a working sample just:

```
import yfinance
df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', start='2019-01-01', end='2021-01-01', period=max, interval=1d)
```

Thanks for any help/suggestion

**ADDITION:**
the for loop approach could be (given a df.reset_index):

```
df['pvi'] = 0.
    
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if index > 0:
        prev_pvi = df.at[index-1, 'pvi']
        prev_close = df.at[index-1, 'Close']
        if row['Close'] > df.at[index-1, 'Volume']:
            pvi = prev_pvi + (row['Close'] - prev_close / prev_close * prev_pvi)
        else: 
            pvi = prev_pvi
    else:
        pvi = 1000 # dummy value
    df.set_value(index, 'pvi', pvi)
```

Comment: Try `df'PVI']` instead of `df.loc['PVI'] `

Comment: @Uts Thanks that was a typo. Now The code run but the result is wrong because the column 'PVI' is not updated and I get a series of zeros inside the timeh.